# Chosen Plugin Not Updated Select Box based on Ajax Result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am working on two select box. One Select Box contain "Product Categories" and Second Select Box Contain Products. As Showing in the following image.
[image]

I can search both box either using product or using category. In the start if search using only products it shows all the products, that is fine. But **problem** is with category.

When i select any category then it should cleared all the products and show only category related products. but it is not updating the result.

**Here is my Js**

```
$("#pcategories").chosen().change(function(){
var val = $(this).val();
var info = 'id=' + val;
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "getproduct.php",             
    data: info,              
    success: function(response){                    
             var len = response.length;

            $("#selectedproducts").empty();
            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var product_id = response[i]['product_id'];
                var product_name = response[i]['product_name'];
                
                $("#selectedproducts").append("<option value='"+product_id+"'>"+product_name+"</option>");
            }
            
    }

  });
});
```

**Here is my HTML**

```
<select name="productcategories" style="width:600px; "class="chzn-select" id="pcategories" required>
<option>Select Category</option>
<?php
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['category_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></option>
<?php
            }
        ?>
```

**Here is HTML for Products**

```
 <select name="product" style="width:600px; "class="chzn-select" id="selectedproducts" required>
<option></option>
<?php

     $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
     $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
     $result->execute();
     for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
   ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['product_code']; ?> - <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?> | Price: <?php echo $row['price']; ?></option>
<?php
            }
        ?>
```

**Where is the error? How can i update the products based on the category ?**

Comment: You need use `.trigger("chosen:updated");` after appending new options i.e : `$("#selectedproducts").trigger("chosen:updated");` .Check [this](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) for more info

Comment: @Swati added this after the appending, but its not updating results and i can know better it is updating or not..first i have to clear the already loaded products..how can i clear the previous products which are in products by default showing ?

Comment: You are already doing that using this line `$("#selectedproducts").empty();` . Are you sure data are return successfully ? .. Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jhefx70b/) .

Comment: Check what does `response` has in it ? Also , you didn't parse it ?

Comment: @Swati `[{"product_id":"36","product_name":"PIANO SWITCH","price":"176.25"},{"product_id":"1211","product_name":"test","price":"45"}]`
this is response which i am getting

Comment: this `$("#selectedproducts").empty(); ` and this `$('#selectedproducts').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');` both are not clearing the box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233959/discussion-between-swati-and-hamza-zafeer).